# c++ vector manipulation

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to remove the biggest int element in a vector and insert it into a new vector.I already have an int that represent the highest number in the vector and one that represents the position of that number.

Heres my code:

```
vector2.push_back(highest);
vector1[highestpos] = vector1[vector1.size()-1];
vector1[vector1.size()-1] = highest;
vector1.pop_back();
```

But it returns an error. Is there anything wrong with this code?

EDIT::::::HERE IS MORE OF MY CODE. The error I get is an assertion error that says vector subscript is out of range.

```
while(vector1.size() > 0)
{
highest = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < vector1.size(); i++)
  {

      if (vector1[i] > highest)
       {
           highest = vector1[i];
           int highestpos = i;
       }
  }

      vector2.push_back(highest);
      vector1[highestpos] = vector1[vector1.size()-1];
      vector1[vector1.size()-1] = highest;
      vector1.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: `it returns an error` could mean many things. Compiler error? Runtime error? What is the compiler or runtime error?

Comment: A bunch of code seems to be missing.

Comment: I don't see any problem... It could be the `highestpos`. Make sure you don't execute that code when `vector1.size() == 0`

Comment: What's the error?  Are you sure `highestpos` is correct?  Also, you don't need to put `highest` into vector1 just so you can pop it out again.  Just leave the original value there.

Comment: Why don't you use max_element() ? Use the algorithm available.

Comment: Your code has no heuristic for determining `the biggest int element`. Much to be desired.

Comment: The posted code won't compile - you declare `highestpos` inside the loop, then use it outside. Do you have another variable called `highestpos` declared before the code you've posted? In that case, then that's your problem. Also, why are you updating the last element of the vector immediately before removing it with `pop_back`?

Comment: @Raze:  No, selection sort, although it's usually done in place by swapping the highest value with the value that happens to be in the right place for the highest value, not putting it in another vector.  Heapsort rearranges the entire vector before starting the sort.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the edit, the problem is that the `highestpos` inside the loop, to which the value of `i` was assigned, is not the same as the `highestpos` outside the loop.

Try a `std::cout << highestpos << '\n';` right before `vector1[highestpos] = ...`

(it may also be helpful to use `max_element()` instead of the hand-written loop to determine the highest value and `vector1.erase()` to delete from the vector, although erase may indeed be less efficient than swap+pop_back)

Comment: This has *O(N)* complexity, whereas the method the OP's attempting will have *O(1)* complexity.

Answer (score 2):

```
 int highestpos = i;
```

You're just defining a variable inside the loop. It doesn't change the value of the variable outside the loop. Change to:

```
 highestpos = i;
```