# C++ vector: Assert when using vector array index -1?

Tags: c++, vector

Essentially, I have code that has a vector of unordered words, a vector2   that stores their priority(and has their position), a vector3 with the priority sorted from highest to lowest.

I want to make a vector 4 with strings that have highest priority first. The bool warning is in the case of repeat priorities.

But every time I run I get an assertion error. I need help.

Here is the original code:

```
bool warning = true;
vector<string> vector4;

for (int a = 0; a < vector2.size(); a++)
{
    for (int q = 0 ; q < vector2.size(); q++)
    {
    if (warning && vector2[a] == vector3[a-1] && a>0)
            {
                   warning = false;
            }
     if (warning && vector2[q] == vector3[a])
             {
                     vector4.push_back(vector1[q]);
             }
       warning = true;
    }

}
```

Here is the code after fixing it using the answers given below:

```
bool warning = true;
vector<string> vector4;

for (int a = 0; a < vector2.size(); a++)
{
    for (int q = 0 ; q < vector2.size(); q++)
    {
    if (a > 0 && warning && vector2[a] == vector3[a-1])
            {
                   warning = false;
            }
     if (warning && vector2[q] == vector3[a])
             {
                     vector4.push_back(vector1[q]);
             }
       warning = true;
    }

}
```

Solved!

Comment: What's the assertion that's being triggered? Also is the if (warning &&vector2[q]...) part a typo or is there a missing space between the '&&' and vector2?

Comment: @Timo: The space doesn't matter.

Comment: You should learn how to use your debugger. You could have quickly spotted where the error was using a debugger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ vector manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228067/c-vector-manipulation)

Comment: @Bo: No, only the title is the same, I checked that right after the question popped up. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
warning && vector2[a] == vector3[a-1]
```

Will give you the assertion on the first loop, because `a == 0`, so `a-1 == -1` which is an invalid index.

Comment: @Emile: Finally I've beaten someone! ;)

Comment: @user: You test in the wrong order, move the `a>0` to the left of the vector tests.

Answer (score 2):

in your loop you do : vector3[a-1]

in the first iteration a = 0 giving a vector3[-1]

This is what makes it assert.

Comment: it still asserts after I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me in the first instance of your loop this statement  is hit:
    if (warning && vector2[a] == vector3[a-1])
when a==0 - Thus you evaluate vector[-1] on the RHS of the ==